# Raphael JS Transform Translate issue

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have two concentrical gear shaped patches, I want them to loop in rotation for ever, I want to center the small one by using Raphael transform method, but when I apply the rotation loop It changes like to move the path from the offset set before to the 0,0 cordinates -upper left corner-, If I delete the line -$gear2.transform('T50,50');- the gears rotate great but the small one position is at 0,0 as you can imagine, how could I achive this+

```
var janddMainGlobals = {


$aniLoop:Raphael.animation({transform:'r360'},6000).repeat(Infinity),
$aniLoopBack:Raphael.animation({transform:'r360'},4000).repeat(Infinity),


};


var janddMainAppi={


ini:function(){



    var $gears = Raphael(document.getElementById('gears'),205,205);

    var $gear1 = $gears.path("M 149.645 26.622 c -0.766 -0.515 -1.54 -0.989 -2.314 -1.477 c 1.849 -3.512 3.662 -7.043 5.436 -10.599 c -6.362 -4.045 -13.309 -7.263 -20.489 -9.684 c -1.615 3.64 -3.187 7.287 -4.721 10.947 c -5.711 -1.875 -11.54 -3.138 -17.401 -3.812 c 0.137 -3.988 0.236 -7.979 0.287 -11.978 c -7.541 -0.67 -15.154 -0.722 -22.657 0.268 c 0.129 3.977 0.3 7.946 0.513 11.916 c -5.891 0.782 -11.7 2.146 -17.325 4.092 c -1.588 -3.63 -3.215 -7.247 -4.884 -10.848 c -7.169 2.448 -13.921 5.984 -20.381 9.942 c 1.835 3.536 3.722 7.056 5.643 10.557 c -4.922 3.23 -9.553 6.986 -13.825 11.239 c -3.025 -2.584 -6.073 -5.141 -9.153 -7.658 c -5.255 5.462 -10.042 11.363 -13.915 17.847 c 3.175 2.375 6.376 4.712 9.599 7.013 c -3.127 5.193 -5.658 10.59 -7.61 16.112 c -3.83 -1.018 -7.667 -2.001 -11.523 -2.94 C 2.37 74.716 0.918 82.208 0 89.726 c 3.911 0.76 7.84 1.479 11.777 2.152 c -0.544 5.945 -0.47 11.908 0.179 17.799 c -3.902 0.746 -7.8 1.533 -11.696 2.367 c 0.948 7.499 2.573 14.939 5.244 22.029 c 3.852 -1.005 7.684 -2.052 11.499 -3.135 c 2.066 5.547 4.683 10.901 7.853 15.98 c -3.206 2.375 -6.394 4.781 -9.551 7.225 c 4.153 6.347 8.905 12.32 14.35 17.603 c 3.028 -2.587 6.028 -5.201 8.997 -7.847 c 3.577 3.428 7.468 6.609 11.708 9.478 c 0.761 0.515 1.538 0.991 2.309 1.479 c -1.849 3.511 -3.665 7.044 -5.436 10.598 c 6.363 4.049 13.31 7.265 20.489 9.683 c 1.62 -3.638 3.188 -7.289 4.722 -10.944 c 5.711 1.877 11.538 3.141 17.401 3.813 c -0.139 3.982 -0.237 7.976 -0.291 11.973 c 7.547 0.675 15.154 0.721 22.662 -0.263 c -0.129 -3.979 -0.299 -7.949 -0.514 -11.916 c 5.893 -0.788 11.698 -2.146 17.324 -4.094 c 1.59 3.63 3.215 7.245 4.883 10.848 c 7.168 -2.448 13.924 -5.983 20.384 -9.946 c -1.84 -3.534 -3.721 -7.051 -5.64 -10.554 c 4.918 -3.229 9.551 -6.985 13.817 -11.238 c 3.028 2.586 6.081 5.142 9.153 7.657 c 5.26 -5.458 10.043 -11.359 13.918 -17.847 c -3.176 -2.376 -6.377 -4.71 -9.598 -7.019 c 3.121 -5.189 5.659 -10.584 7.609 -16.106 c 3.828 1.021 7.668 2.003 11.525 2.94 c 2.553 -7.152 4.004 -14.645 4.922 -22.161 c -3.916 -0.764 -7.842 -1.479 -11.777 -2.158 c 0.54 -5.945 0.467 -11.905 -0.182 -17.792 c 3.904 -0.752 7.801 -1.539 11.691 -2.375 c -0.945 -7.498 -2.57 -14.937 -5.239 -22.026 c -3.851 1.004 -7.687 2.052 -11.5 3.136 c -2.065 -5.551 -4.685 -10.906 -7.849 -15.982 c 3.205 -2.375 6.391 -4.781 9.547 -7.227 c -4.154 -6.346 -8.902 -12.318 -14.348 -17.596 c -3.032 2.582 -6.029 5.198 -9 7.84 C 157.768 32.675 153.875 29.488 149.645 26.622 Z M 158.914 139.861 c -22.012 32.539 -66.233 41.07 -98.773 19.057 C 27.603 136.905 19.07 92.682 41.082 60.143 c 22.016 -32.54 66.237 -41.072 98.775 -19.059 C 172.398 63.099 180.93 107.32 158.914 139.861 Z");

    var $gear2 = $gears.path("M 74.822 13.311 c -0.383 -0.257 -0.77 -0.494 -1.157 -0.738 c 0.925 -1.756 1.831 -3.521 2.718 -5.299 c -3.182 -2.022 -6.654 -3.631 -10.244 -4.842 c -0.809 1.82 -1.594 3.644 -2.361 5.474 c -2.855 -0.938 -5.77 -1.569 -8.7 -1.906 c 0.068 -1.994 0.118 -3.99 0.144 -5.989 c -3.771 -0.335 -7.577 -0.361 -11.329 0.134 c 0.065 1.988 0.15 3.973 0.256 5.958 c -2.945 0.391 -5.85 1.073 -8.662 2.046 c -0.794 -1.815 -1.607 -3.624 -2.442 -5.424 c -3.584 1.224 -6.96 2.992 -10.19 4.971 c 0.918 1.768 1.861 3.528 2.821 5.278 c -2.461 1.615 -4.776 3.493 -6.912 5.62 c -1.513 -1.292 -3.037 -2.57 -4.577 -3.829 c -2.627 2.731 -5.021 5.681 -6.958 8.923 c 1.588 1.188 3.188 2.356 4.799 3.506 c -1.563 2.597 -2.829 5.295 -3.805 8.056 c -1.915 -0.509 -3.834 -1 -5.762 -1.47 C 1.185 37.357 0.459 41.104 0 44.862 c 1.956 0.38 3.92 0.74 5.889 1.076 c -0.272 2.973 -0.235 5.954 0.09 8.9 c -1.951 0.373 -3.9 0.767 -5.848 1.184 c 0.474 3.749 1.287 7.47 2.622 11.015 c 1.926 -0.503 3.842 -1.026 5.75 -1.567 c 1.033 2.773 2.342 5.45 3.927 7.99 c -1.603 1.188 -3.197 2.391 -4.776 3.612 c 2.077 3.173 4.453 6.16 7.175 8.801 c 1.514 -1.293 3.014 -2.601 4.499 -3.923 c 1.788 1.714 3.733 3.305 5.854 4.738 c 0.38 0.258 0.769 0.496 1.154 0.739 c -0.924 1.756 -1.832 3.522 -2.718 5.299 c 3.182 2.024 6.654 3.633 10.244 4.842 c 0.81 -1.819 1.594 -3.645 2.361 -5.473 c 2.855 0.938 5.769 1.57 8.7 1.907 c -0.069 1.991 -0.119 3.987 -0.146 5.986 c 3.774 0.337 7.577 0.36 11.331 -0.132 c -0.064 -1.989 -0.149 -3.975 -0.257 -5.958 c 2.946 -0.394 5.849 -1.073 8.662 -2.047 c 0.795 1.815 1.607 3.623 2.441 5.424 c 3.584 -1.224 6.962 -2.991 10.192 -4.973 c -0.92 -1.768 -1.861 -3.525 -2.82 -5.277 c 2.459 -1.614 4.775 -3.492 6.908 -5.619 c 1.515 1.293 3.041 2.571 4.577 3.829 c 2.63 -2.729 5.021 -5.68 6.959 -8.924 c -1.588 -1.188 -3.188 -2.354 -4.799 -3.509 c 1.561 -2.595 2.829 -5.292 3.805 -8.054 c 1.914 0.511 3.834 1.002 5.763 1.471 c 1.276 -3.576 2.002 -7.322 2.461 -11.081 c -1.958 -0.382 -3.921 -0.739 -5.889 -1.079 c 0.27 -2.973 0.233 -5.953 -0.091 -8.896 c 1.952 -0.376 3.9 -0.769 5.846 -1.187 c -0.473 -3.749 -1.285 -7.468 -2.62 -11.013 c -1.925 0.502 -3.843 1.026 -5.75 1.568 c -1.032 -2.775 -2.342 -5.453 -3.924 -7.991 c 1.603 -1.187 3.195 -2.39 4.773 -3.613 c -2.077 -3.173 -4.451 -6.159 -7.174 -8.798 c -1.516 1.291 -3.015 2.599 -4.5 3.92 C 78.884 16.337 76.938 14.744 74.822 13.311 Z M 79.457 69.931 C 68.451 86.2 46.34 90.466 30.07 79.459 C 13.801 68.453 9.535 46.341 20.541 30.071 c 11.008 -16.27 33.119 -20.536 49.388 -9.529 C 86.199 31.549 90.465 53.66 79.457 69.931 Z");


    $gear1.attr({stroke:'none', fill:'#0B1518'});
    $gear1.animate(janddMainGlobals.$aniLoop);

    $gear2.attr({stroke:'none',fill:'#082735'})
    $gear2.transform('T50,50');
    $gear2.animate(janddMainGlobals.$aniLoopBack);



},



};
```

online example. http://www.yourteamwork.com/jandd/

Comment: Would be helpful to have it on a fiddle to be sure, but I suspect whats happening is that your original transform is being used to animate away from. So maybe you will need to include the original transform in the animation string, so $aniLoopBack:Raphael.animation({transform:'T50,50r360'},4000).repeat(Infinity) see if that helps, and will put as an answer if it does.

Comment: I just added the T50,50 like you said and now is working as I espected. Thanks for your help man, gteetings. http://jsfiddle.net/djburner/oh6xrzyL/2/

Comment: I forgot where to accept the answer, if anybody can do it Ian is right, if not, where do I do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Animating, if there is a transform already in place, it will use that as a reference to transform from, as the new transform currently doesn't include the translate offset.

So in this case, we need to include the additional transform. Note, you can build these up and have as many as you want, just remember the order of transformations is important (so a rotation followed by a translation, is different to a translation followed by a rotation).

So instead of having

```
$aniLoopBack:Raphael.animation({transform:'r360'},4000).repeat(Infinity)
```

Change this to

```
$aniLoopBack:Raphael.animation({transform:'T50,50r360'},4000).repeat(Infinity)
```

This will then include the new translate part of the transform in each animation.